# flagging "Why the downvote" comments

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I am curious if it is right to flag the "Why the downvote?" comments; if so, what would these be flagged as?

Comment: Not constructive?

Comment: That's what I am thinking @DavidPostill, I am not entirely sure, as they could be 'Obsolete'

Comment: I just realised I wrote `downvote the 'Why the downvote?' comments` LOL, need my coffee

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy awesome - not sure how I missed that!

Comment: @SabreTooth _"LOL, need my coffee"_ [Well, here you go ...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6wNQa.jpg?s=128&g=1)

Comment: Am also a bit distracted - in the path of a nasty cyclone

Comment: This is old, but the thought process behind "this user was confused why people are treating his post in an unusual way, and asking for more info" - is to delete the comment? SO has gotten so lost in it's own meta - we'd be better off imagining each user as a paying customer.

Comment: I bet this was in response to my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285043/freebase-how-to-use-the-freebase-rdf-latest/28290808#28290808 where @SabreTooth (now user4469467 since they quit) downvoted my answer out of spite because I answered a question they voted to close.  The OP was grateful for both answers, yet they were both downvoted by a user who's voting history consisted mostly of downvoting things.  That makes for a crappy SO user experience, particularly for new users.

Comment: Just saw my similar comment was removed from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43627577/171318. Since I'm not a every day javascript user I was pretty interested. The comment had even been upvoted but was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They're not really adding any value to the answer (or question), so I'd say "Too chatty" or "Not constructive".

To clarify:  I'd personally lean more towards "too chatty", as the whole back-and-forth of why this was downvoted is going to lead to a lot of unnecessary chatter, and invite extended discussion.

Comment: Thank you for that - I am leaning towards 'Not constructive'

Comment: I'd lean a wee bit more towards "too chatty", frankly.  Comments of that sort are only inviting an open-ended discussion.

Comment: That's a good point too - I have just been seeing a lot of them (and found a data thingie that finds them

Comment: Yup, I definitely see your point in the comment chain here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377141/select-all-rows-with-same-ids-if-one-column-contains-a-particular-value/28377398#28377398

Comment: Either one of those flag reasons should get a "why the downvote?" comment deleted without hesitation.

Comment: I plainly disagree with this "not adding any value to the answer" statement, thus I've downvoted this answer.